# Snap to face problem

Tags: faces, snapping, project

I am just startying to learn Blender and I've encountered an issue I can't manage to solve. I'm trying to place a circle onto a curved mesh. Normally it shoul snap onto it but no matter what i try the circle isn't setting onto the projected mesh entirely. What might the issue be? I was thinking maybe because the larger mesh is a double curved object, but still I doubt its impossible to do it... [image] [image]

Comment: Which blender version are you using? Is it 4.0 alpha?

Comment: No, Im using 3.6

Comment: Are you trying to snap to a (non-existent) mirrored half of a mesh?

Comment: Is it 3.6.1? Coz I don't see all the options in 3.6

Comment: @RobinBetts I just realized that I am. But i was following a tutorial and he didnt sayanything about it causing an issue, he actually light've done it this way...

Comment: @Akshay2005 I'm not sure tbh, i got the latest availble and it was a couple of weeks ago.. What options?

Comment: These: Include Active, Include Edited and Include Non-Edited. They might have come with 3.6.1.  So I can't recreate the settings. Maybe someone else will help. Sorry

Comment: @Akshay2005 Both 3.5.1 and 3.6.1 come with those options available for Face Project but they're only available in Edit mode.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are using snap in edit mode?
If you do that it's going to look at the geometry of the chair without that subdivision modifier and it's gonna align the object based on a weird orientation of the mesh. (Top figure)
[image]
Using it in object mode with the rivets as a separate object will make them align on the final surface of the chair based on the rivet's local orientation, which will give you the result you probably want (Bottom). Just make sure the rivet has it's rotation reset to 0 and it's pointing up

Comment: Thank you for your answer! 
Yes, I was doing it mainly in edit mode... I did just try on object mode and the result is pretty much the same. But to confirm the 2nd image does represent what I'm trying to achieve

Comment: I was thinking maybe there might be something wrong with the chair surface, although I did follow the tutorial maybe i messed up somewhere without realising

Comment: @archiheart I'm not sure which tutorial you were watching, but in the one that Blender Guru did [here](https://youtu.be/KzA5fOIq8Qw?list=PLjEaoINr3zgEL9UjPTLWQhLFAK7wVaRMR&t=1181), he is actually in Object mode when he's demonstrating the technique. (That tutorial was done in Blender 2.8 so snapping doesn't have nearly as many options on the dropdown but the technique is the same.) –

Comment: @archiheart try remaking the rivet object from scratch and using snap only in object mode. If the mesh of the object got slightly rotated while using it in edit mode at some point it's never going to align properly

Comment: @JohnEason its the tutorial I was following.

Comment: @JohnEason Is it possible to make the entirety of the rivet in object mode? I did however try to just add a circle in object mode and then move it onto the back of the chair but the result is the same

Comment: Worked for me when I did that tutorial a couple of years ago. Where is the origin of your rivet? - Try changing from 'Center' to 'Median' in the face snapping options and see if that makes any difference.

Comment: No. You can't make the whole rivet in Object mode. Why do you ask?

Comment: @JohnEason because you told me to do it

Comment: @JohnEason there is no change between the use of median and center. what do you mean by the origin of the rivet? When creating it sets to the center world I believer

Comment: I think we're going to need to see your Blend file before we go any further. You can do that via https://blend-exchange.com/ following the instructions on that page to copy the link and then edit and paste the link into your question. We'll then be able to see exactly what's going on.

Comment: Just checked Andrew's tutorial and he has 'Snap With' set to 'Closest' not 'Center' as you have on your image. Might be worth trying that before you share your file.